# Spring: Bind a collection on controller parameter

Tags: java, spring, data-binding, collections

I've seen lots of questions similar to mine but, I couldn't find a solution to this problem so far.

I am implementing a grid filtering and pagination on Spring + Hibernate. The `load()` method must receive the specific parameters for pagination (`page`, `start` and `limit`) and a **list of key-value parameter for filtering**, which is being the problem.

The parameters are coming like that:

```
page:1
start:0
limit:23
filter:[{"operator":"like","value":"tes","property":"desc"},{"operator":"like","value":"teste","property":"model_desc"}]
```

or (encoded version):

```
page=1&start=0&limit=23&filter=%5B%7B%22operator%22%3A%22like%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22tes%22%2C%22property%22%3A%22desc%22%7D%2C%7B%22operator%22%3A%22like%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22teste%22%2C%22property%22%3A%22model_desc%22%7D%5D
```

The filter parameter is coming as a `String` and the problem is to make Spring parse that either as something like `ArrayList<Map<String,String>>` or `ArrayList<SomeFilterClass>`.

This is the signature of my controller method (the commented lines are all not working, they are here just to show what I've tried so far):

```
public Map<String, Object> loadData(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = true) int page,
            @RequestParam(value = "start", required = true) int start,
            @RequestParam(value = "limit", required = true) int limit,
//          @ModelAttribute("filter") ArrayList<Map<String, String>> filter) {
//          @RequestParam(value = "filter", required = false) Map<String, Object>[] filter) {
//          @RequestParam(value = "filter", required = false) List<Map<String, String>> filter) {
            @ModelAttribute("filter") RemoteFilter filter)
```

This class, `RemoteFilter`, is a wrapper class that I built, following a suggestion from other posts but, it didn't work also. Its structure is:

```
public class RemoteFilter {

    private ArrayList<Filter> filter;

    //Getters and Setters....

    class Filter {
        private String operator;

        private String value;

        private String property;

        //Getters and Setters....
    }
}
```

I will be very glad if anybody help me with that.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are invoking the Controller via Ajax, is there any reason you using GET (and have to URL encode JSON) instead ofPOSTing and using Spring @RequestBody to convert the JSON into a Java object?

Answer (score 1):

Try to POST the data instead of using GET, Spring only offers JSON to Java conversion when data is posted.

Post

```
{ 
    page:1
    start:0
    limit:23
    filter:[{"operator":"like","value":"tes","property":"desc"},{"operator":"like","value":"teste","property":"model_desc"}]
}
```

And have the controller use @RequestBody

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "url", 
    produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
    consumes = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Map<String, Object> loadData(@RequestBody RemoteFilter filter) {

}
```

The response uses `Object`as the Map value type. This will work, but using an un-typped return value is a bad thing in general.

Comment: Hi @KlausGroenbaek thanks for replying. I forgot to put the `@RequestMapping` annotation but it is a `POST` request already: `@RequestMapping(value="/load", method=RequestMethod.POST)`. I changed it to `@RequestBody(required=false) RemoteFilter filter` and I got a error 415 (Unsupported Media Type). I thing this occurred because on first load, the parameter filter is not sent, that's why required is set to false.

Comment: 415 means that the Content-type is incorrect. If you are posting from a browser it should add content-type=application/json automatically, in Spring you configure what a controllor method consumes and produces. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: It's sending as `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. But one question, I'm still receiving the other parameters (`page`, `start` and `limit`). Does `@RequestBody` works in this situation still? 
`@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page,
@RequestParam(value = "start", required = false) int start,
@RequestParam(value = "limit", required = false) int limit,
@RequestBody(required=false) RemoteFilter filter)`

Comment: ```Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded``` is used for form submission. The filter parameter suggested that you were sending JSON. Does the page reload when you change page, or do you use JavaScript to load the new data, and then replace part of the page?

Comment: hmm got it.. First the page loads (without `filter` parameter), then user type any text on column filter and a new request is sent to server with filter data.. then the server returns new data and the page is refreshed..but, in all situations, the other parameters is sent  (page, start and limit) that's why I think `@RequestBody` may not work, right?

Comment: If you do full page reloads ```RequestBody``` will not work. Most (if not every new) solutions today load paginated data using Ajax calls from JavaScript. What you are doing is not impossible, but not normal either. I think it may be possible to solve this using Spring form-binding, but I'm not going to try and write the example to figure it out.

Comment: Well, I noticed something here.. using `@RequestParam` it rejects saying that there's no strategy for converting String to RemoteFilter: `500 - Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'br.com....RemoteFilter'; etc...`. If I add a constructor from a `String` to `RemoteFilter` it receives the parameter without throwing error but, does not parse it also.. What I first intended to, is to make Spring parse this automatically but, if there's no way for doing that, I can parse the String in this constructor. Do you think is there any way for parsing it automatically?

Comment: You should have ```@RequestParam("filter") String filter```, it is not possible to convert it directly to a ```RemoteFilter```. You have to convert it from a String to a RemoteFilter manually. Technically it is possible to convert to a String to an object, but it is way beyond you current level, and I don't have time to do it for you (and I think it would be counter productive for your overall development skills). My recommendation is that you read the Spring MVC documentation (chapter 22), once you understand all the terminology.